# Chart.js gráfico de barras trabajo con colores

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

js estoy graficando el porciento de cumplimiento de los planes de las áreas por las que esta distribuida mi empresa, se grafican  2 listas diferentes, aqui dejo como lo tengo:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: 'bar',
  data: {
   labels: listaAreas,
    datasets: [{
    label: 'USA',
    backgroundColor: listacoloresUSA,
  data: cumplimientoUSA,
}, {
  label: 'EURO',
  backgroundColor: listacoloresEURO,
  data: cumplimientoEURO,
}]
}
});
```

las listas de los cumplimientos es la lista de los porcientos, listacoloresUSA y listacoloresEURO son las listas de colores en esta lista en la clase controladora mientras lleno la lista de cumplimiento lleno la lista de colores para cada barra pero cuando el primer color de las listas es rojo(no ha cumplido) el color de la leyenda tambien me lo pone en rojo y lo que quiero es poner en la leyenda 3 labels y 2 que  el color que tenga al lado sean los colores de cumplimiento(azul y verde)  y el rojo de incumplimiento, espero que me entiendan estoy pendiente al correo 
En la imagen muestro como me sale quiero que cuando sea mayor de 20 la varra sea de color azul o verde en la imagen no cambia y no se como poner otro label en la leyenda  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: haz un ejecutable plz , para ver que quieres lograr.

Comment: Por favor, redacta mejor tu pregunta. Entiendo que quieres cambiar el color de las barras en función de su valor (es fácil de conseguir) y añadir un label más a la leyenda pero deberías explicar mejor si eso es lo que quieres conseguir.

Comment: @Kiko_L   aqui  dejo un ejemplo y la pregunta tambien de lo que quiero https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154273/colores-en-la-grafica-de-barras-de-chart-js