# Colores en la grafica de Barras de Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Estoy graficando el porciento de cumplimiento de los planes de las áreas por las que esta distribuida mi empresa, se grafican 2 listas diferentes que se llenan en la controladora y envio los datos por ajax donde recibo las listas de los por cientos y la de los colores y me muestra asi como lo muestro en el ejemplo, en la leyenda me pone el primer color que viene en la lista de colores y no me sirve asi , quisiera mostrar en la leyenda 3 colores el verde, azul y el rojo me podrian ayudar

```js
var labels=['Aplicaciones','Comunicaciones','Telematica','Ofimatica'];
var ColorCumplidoCUP=["red","#2ecc71","#2ecc71","red"];
var ColorCumplidoCUC=[ "red","red","red","#3498db"];
var cumplidoCUP=[40.55,100.00,120.00,90.00];
var cumplidoCUC=[60.00,90.00,80.00,110,00];
      
var ctx3 = document.getElementById("PCplanmesXarea");
    var PCplanmesArea = new Chart(ctx3, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'CUP',
                    data: cumplidoCUP,
                    backgroundColor: ColorCumplidoCUP,
                    borderWidth: 1
                },
                {
                    label: 'CUC',
                    data: cumplidoCUC,
                    backgroundColor: ColorCumplidoCUC,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
        },
        options: {

            events: false,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {display: true, labelString: 'Áreas'}
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 150,
                        callback: function (value) {
                            return value + '%';
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
            animation: {
                duration: 800,
                easing: "easeOutQuart",
                onComplete: function () {
                    var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
                    ctx.font = '12px LatoRegular, Helvetica,sans-serif';
                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
                    this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
                            var m = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model;
                            ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i] + '%', m.x + 1, m.y - 5);
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 ">
            <h4 class="col-md-offset-2">Por Ciento del Plan Cumplido </h4>
            <canvas id="PCplanmesXarea" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
        </div>
```

Comment: Cada leyenda corresponde a un _dataset_. ¿Que valor de leyenda le das al tercer color si solo usas dos valores de análisis? Para tener tres leyendas, necesitas tres valores. Un tercer _dataset_ vacío te permite tener un tercer elemento en leyenda. Pero te deja un hueco "raro".

Comment: A esta bien y como podria ponerle el color estático a cada leyenda sino me sucede lo mismo que en el grafico que puse me pone de color en la leyenda el primer color que tiene la lista de colores y no es lo que me hace falta

Comment: @Antonio Stack Overflow no funciona como un foro, no tienes que publicar respuestas para comunicarte con los usuarios, para ello puedes escribir comentarios. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Comment: si lo se pero no me dejaba poner un comentario y puse una respuesta